# What do various clipboard/drag-and-drop formats mean?

Tags: .net, windows, drag-and-drop, clipboard

I was playing around with drag and drop. I made a sample application and dropped a file from folder *[My Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder#File_system_directories)* onto my application. Here's what `e.Data.GetFormats()` returned:

- Shell IDList Array
- UsingDefaultDragImage
- DragImageBits
- DragContext
- DragSourceHelperFlags
- InShellDragLoop
- FileDrop
- FileNameW
- FileName
- IsShowingLayered
- DragWindow
- IsComputingImage
- DropDescription
- DisableDragText
- ComputedDragImage
- IsShowingText

What do each of these mean and how to decode and use them?

Googling each of them didn't yield any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileDrop is standard, covered by the DataFormats class.  Shell IDList and FileName/W are common for Windows Explorer.  The rest of them are all custom.  By their names, it sounds like they enhance the D+D feedback when you drag to other Microsoft apps, like Media Player.  This stuff is poorly documented, possibly intentional.

Answer (score 4):

**DragImageBits** describes the image that's displayed when you drag stuff. Its header is described by [SHDRAGIMAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759778%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
var data = e.Data.GetData("DragImageBits") as MemoryStream;
var buffer = new byte[24];
data.Read(buffer, 0, 24);
int w = buffer[0] + (buffer[1] << 8) + (buffer[2] << 16) + (buffer[3] << 24);
int h = buffer[4] + (buffer[5] << 8) + (buffer[6] << 16) + (buffer[7] << 24);
// Stride accounts for any padding bytes at the end of each row. For 32 bit
// bitmaps there are none, so stride = width * size of each pixel in bytes.
int stride = width * 4;
// x and y is the relative position between the top left corner of the image and
// the mouse cursor.
int x = buffer[8] + (buffer[9] << 8) + (buffer[10] << 16) + (buffer[11] << 24);
int y = buffer[12] + (buffer[13] << 8) + (buffer[14] << 16) + (buffer[15] << 24);
buffer = new byte[stride * h];
// The image is stored upside down, so we flip it as we read it.
for (int i = (h - 1) * stride; i >= 0; i -= stride) data.Read(buffer, i, stride);
BitmapSource.Create(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, buffer, stride);
```

One should still use [DragDropHelper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx) instead for better compatibility.

Comment: +1 - I used some of this code for a different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8468171/25216 While this works, it can be simplified by using a BinaryReader.

Comment: I experience trouble when drawing the colors.. Most colors match  perfectly the original, but White regions appear in Gray?