# Image/Jpeg Base 64 to Image

Tags: c#, image

I have image/jped base64 code like this,

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA......
```

I need, convert to image this code and save file as jpeg file. And I figured the Windows Form (C#). Insert to Textbox and button. Insert the base 64 code (the code is above) in textbox and click the button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            string imageDataParsed = textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.IndexOf(',') + 1);
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageDataParsed);

            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms1);
            img.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\Images\\1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

File save as a jpeg. But this file seems like this on Windows Photo Viewer
[image]

But when I run on the Google Chrome this base 64 code, there is no problem. Viewing nice on Google Chrome browser.

Summary my question, I need base64 code to Image and save this file my server as jpeg file.
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Are any parts of the base64 UrlEncoded or have other special characters when coming from the text box?

Comment: So far looks like you just don't get complete string. Please make sure to update your sample with inline string that is *small* and *complete* example of base64 string that does show behavior you observing.

Comment: This code works for me. I also tried it with a truncated Base64 string (I thought that is your problem), but I got a FormatException and the image was not saved.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov  I have complete code. Because when I test on chrome browser, this picture showing perfectly. But when I save as file, not showing perfectly same code.

Comment: I've created a simple jpeg data url and it is opened both in chrome (as a src of a img element) and in Windows Photo Viewer after it is saved by your code. It seems there is something special with your image. Could you please share the exact data the issue can be reproduced on?

Answer (score 1):

Convert Base64 straight to file avoid loading it into a Image, this way it should be all in-tact like the original image, of course this still doesn't solve your image showing problem.

```
byte[] newfile = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\path\to\file.jpg", newfile);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I tested now, didn't solve my picture showing problem? :(

Comment: Then your base64 image is a corrupted jpeg image or maybe it's not suppose to jpeg but rather png or gif? you should check the header in a hex editor I know other image formats could show up in Window Photo Viewer with the wrong extensions but glitch up.

Answer (score -1):

i think the problem is big endian and little endian mismatch see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness